# Bootstrap-sass 3.3.5 not adding styling on any page (nav bar, hero box, nothing is working)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

None of the styles for bootstrap are working on my rails website. Followed the instructions step by step from https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails to install bootstrap.

Here is what the page looks like, I'll post the files below for installation, maybe I did something wrong. Any help would be super appreciated!

Image of website: http://www.screencast.com/t/uviumiXa

**Here is the application.css.scss:**

```css
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

$baseFontFamily: Oxygen;
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen);

body {
 padding-top:60px;
}

.footer {
 margin-top: 50px;
 color: #111111;
 a {
  color: $gray;
 }
}

/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**Application.js:**

```html
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**Gemfile:**

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'pg'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 5'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do

  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end
```

What seems incorrect for all this?

Comment: My best guess is that you should change `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to `//= require bootstrap` in your `application.js` manifest file.  Try that first... I would also separate out any custom css/scss into a separate file like `custom.css.scss` and just use `application.css` for manifest directives.  This is more just good practice although you should understand in what order the asset pipeline will include your custom css if you choose to keep it in your manifest file.

Comment: Also I'm assuming you have included your manifest files in your application layout (css and js).

Comment: @steveklein I went ahead and changed //= require bootstrap-sprockets to //= require bootstrap in application.js, I created custom.css.scss and put all the scss code in there. - Still didn't apply the bootstrap styles. What do you mean by manifest file?

Comment: I strongly recommend you take a moment and read the [Rails asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).  It explains how Rails handles assets.  I have read and referred to it many times and It has saved me hours of pain and suffering.  Once you do that, let us know if you are still stuck.